# Laravel Eloquent relational function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

1. Table Users => id, first_name, ...
2. Table Tags => id, name
3. Pivot Table user_tags => id, user_id, tag_id, ...

I'm using this in User Model:

```
public function tags()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'user_tag');
}
```

And this in TagsController:

```
$users = User::with(['tags'])->get();
```

What I need is to get only users that have tags with empty users tag

Comment: Do you want only those users who are having tags?

Comment: Yes, Here it is getting all users who have tags and not

Answer (score 1):

You can query records based on presence or absence of related records.

```php
//Get all users with tags, only get the users which have tags.
$users = User::with('tags')->has('tags')->get();

//Get all users which do not have tags
$users = User::doesntHave('tags')->get();
```

Laravel docs:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence